# UITextField `setText` in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

With `Objective-C`, I can override the `setText` function by following codes. The `text` is a property of `UITextField`, and I sub-class it for some custom UI design.

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
   [super setText:text];
   ....
}
```

My question is, how to do such thing by **Swift** ?

There is no such function `setText` when I program with Swift. How to override the `setter` and `getter` methods of property with Swift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your subclass of `UITextField`, override the `text`property :

```
override public var text:String?  {
    didSet {            
         NSLog("text = \(text)")
    }
}
```

Be careful though, this `didSet` observer is called **after** the property was changed, so you can't decide to revert to the previous value since it's already replaced. 
If you want to perform operations before the value is changed, you can use the `willSet` observer, which is called before you value change.

```
override public var text:String?  {
    didSet {            
         NSLog("text = \(text)")
    }
    willSet {
        NSLog("will change from \(text) to \(newValue)")
    }
}
```

Small example with this code :

```
var testTextfield = MyTextFieldClass()
testTextfield.text = "test"
testTextfield.text = "test1"
```

And the output is

```
will change from Optional("") to Optional("test")
text = Optional("test")
will change from Optional("test") to Optional("test1")
Optional("test1")
```

Comment: It works. But compiler said, change `public` to `internal`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use variable observers in this case.

```
var variableName: someType = expression {
    willSet(valueName) {
    // code called before the value is changed
    }
    didSet(valueName) {
    // code called after the value is changed
    }
}
```

A practical example.

```
“class StepCounter {
    var totalSteps: Int = 0 {
        willSet(newTotalSteps) {
            print("About to set totalSteps to \(newTotalSteps)")
        }
        didSet {
            if totalSteps > oldValue  {
                print("Added \(totalSteps - oldValue) steps")
            }
        }
    }
}”
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1 Prerelease).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l